# Cant bundle angular app in gulp build

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, model-view-controller, gulp, angular5

Im trying to bundle my app so that I can push it to the test server using Gulp. This is my gulp file. It is not done yet, (Build is supposed to also run vendor-js) but I get an error when it runs bundle:app. This is my gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
tsc = require('gulp-typescript'),
Builder = require('systemjs-builder'),
tslint = require('gulp-tslint'),
sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
tscConfig = require('./tsconfig.json');


gulp.task('lint', function () {
return gulp.src('app/**/*.ts')
    .pipe(tslint({ formatter: 'prose' }))
    .pipe(tslint.report());});

gulp.task('compile', ['lint'], function () {
return gulp.src('app/**/*.ts')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(tsc(tscConfig.compilerOptions))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));});

var vendorJS = [
'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js',
'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
'node_modules/systemjs.config.js'];

var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('vendor-js', function () {
return gulp.src(vendorJS)
    .pipe(concat('vendor.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));});   

var systemjsBuilder = require('gulp-systemjs-builder');

gulp.task('bundle:app', function () {
var builder = systemjsBuilder();
builder.loadConfigSync('./systemjs.config.js');

builder.buildStatic('dist/js/main.js', 'app.min.js', {})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));});

gulp.task('build', ['compile', 'bundle:app']);
```

The error I am getting is :

> Unhandled rejection Error on fetch for dist/js/app.module at
>   file:///C:/path/dist/js/app.module Loading dist/js/main.js Error:
>   ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\Dev\path\dist\js\app.module' at Error (native)

Do you guys have any suggestions on how to make this work and compress the whole thing to something like "app.min.js" anyone?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to resolve this? I too have a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60179113/angular-4-gulp-build-task-with-systemjs-returns-error-enoent/