# Angular 4: Gulp Build Task with SystemJS returns Error ENOENT

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, gulp, systemjs

**UPDATED: 2020.02.13** - Looks like someone else fell through this same problem too - however, no solution. See [Github](https://github.com/openmarco/gulp-systemjs-builder/issues/5).

A specific set of GulpJS errors are surfacing when trying to build out an Angular 4 Web App with SystemJS.

What's odd is that usually this build script works. There were no edits to the GulpJS or SystemJS file. I'm curious if something in the node/npm ecosystem changes this assumption. At any rate, your thoughts on a fix would be appreciated.

My **Windows 10** machine is currently installed with **Node version 10.14.0** and **npm version of 6.9.0**.

When executing `npm run build:dev` The errors from Gulp show in the terminal as:

```
Unhandled rejection Error on fetch for app/main.js at file:///C:/Users/Mark/Desktop/Development/Bitbucket/Angular4App/app/main.js
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Development\Bitbucket\Angular4App\app\main.js'
```

To be clear, the above file being `main.js` does truly exist in the file system.

Gulp continues, and the remainder of the build completes. But when testing out the final build, the app doesn't load and this asset is missing from the final build:

Noticeably missing from the final build artifact:

`app/assets/js/app/app.js`

[image]

**gulpfile.js:**

```
'use strict';

// Install required dependencies for gulp task automation.
var gulp = require('gulp');
var del = require('del');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var systemjsBuilder = require('gulp-systemjs-builder')
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');

/**
* Compile Sass files and keep them in their respective locations.
*/
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    console.log('Building Sass files.');
    return gulp.src('app/**/*.scss', { base: './' })
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});

/**
* Watch Sass files.
*/
gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
    console.log('Watching Sass files.');
    gulp.watch('app/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});

/**
* Compile TypeScript app to JS.
*/
gulp.task('compile:ts', function() {
    console.log('Compile TypeScript files into JavaScript files for Angular 4 App.');
    var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');
    return tsProject.src()
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(tsProject())
        .js.pipe(gulp.dest('app'));
});

/**
* Generate systemjs-based bundle (app/app.js).
*/
gulp.task('bundle:app', function() {
    console.log('Generate app.js file for Angular 4 App.');
    var builder = systemjsBuilder();
    builder.loadConfigSync('./system.config.js');

    builder.buildStatic('app', 'app/app.js', {
        minify: false,
        mangle: false
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('portal/app/assets/js'));
})

/**
* Copy and bundle CSS dependencies into one file, vendors.min.css.
*/
gulp.task('bundle:vendorCSS', function() {
    console.log('Copy and bundle dependencies into one file, vendors.css.');
    return gulp.src([
        'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
        'node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css',
        'node_modules/bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css'
    ])
    .pipe(concat('vendors.min.css'))
    .pipe(cleanCSS({
       level: {
           1: {
            specialComments: false
           }
       } 
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('portal/app/assets/css/vendors'));
});

/**
* Copy and bundle CSS dependencies into one file, app.component.min.css.
*/
gulp.task('bundle:appCSS', function() {
    console.log('Copy and bundle dependencies into one file, vendors.css.');
    return gulp.src([
        'app/assets/css/app.component.css'
    ])
    .pipe(concat('app.component.min.css'))
    .pipe(cleanCSS({
        level: {
            1: {
             specialComments: false
            }
        } 
     }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('portal/app/assets/css'));
});

/**
* Copy and bundle FONT dependencies into one file, vendors.css.
*/
gulp.task('bundle:vendorFONT', function() {
    console.log('Copy font dependencies to Angular 4 App\'s portal directory.');
    return gulp.src([
        'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot*',
        'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg*',
        'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf*',
        'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff*',
        'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2*',
        'node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf*',
        'node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff*',
        'node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2*'
    ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('portal/app/assets/css/fonts'));
});

/**
* Copy and bundle JAVASCRIPT dependencies into one file, vendors.js.
*/
gulp.task('bundle:polyfillsJS', function() {
    console.log('Copy and bundle dependencies into one file, polyfills.js.');
    return gulp.src([
        'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js',
        'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
        'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
        'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js'
    ])
    .pipe(concat('polyfills.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('portal/app/assets/js/polyfills'));
});

/**
* Copy dependencies loaded from SystemJS into portal directory.
*/
gulp.task('copy:vendorJS', function () {
    console.log('Copy 3rd party dependencies loaded from SystemJS to Angular 4 App\'s portal directory.');
    return gulp.src([
        '@angular/common/**',
        '@angular/compiler/**',
        '@angular/core/**',
        '@angular/forms/**',
        '@angular/http/**',
        '@angular/platform-browser/**',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/**',
        '@angular/router/**',
        '@ngx-translate/core/**',
        '@ngx-translate/http-loader/**',
        '@types/highcharts/**',
        'angular2-highcharts/**',
        'animate.css/**',
        'bootstrap/**',
        'bootstrap-daterangepicker/**',
        'bootstrap-social/**',
        'core-js/**',
        'font-awesome/**',
        'highcharts/**',
        'jquery/**',
        'jquery-slimscroll/**',
        'lodash/**',
        'moment/**',
        "ng2-breadcrumb/**",
        'ng2-daterangepicker/**',
        'ngx-bootstrap/**',
        'ngx-infinite-scroll/bundles/**',
        'reflect-metadata/**',
        'rxjs/**',
        'systemjs/**',
        'zone.js/**'        
    ], { cwd: 'node_modules/**' }) /* Glob required here. */
    .pipe(gulp.dest('portal/app/assets/js/vendors'));
});

/**
* Get the LOWER ENVIRONMENT index.html file to the root of the portal directory.
*/
gulp.task('index-lower', function(){
    console.log('Get LOWER ENVIRONMENT index.html file to the root of Angular 4 App\'s portal directory.');
    return gulp.src(['static_lower/index.html'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('portal'));
});

/**
* Copy the LOWER ENVIRONMENT app core files to the portal directory.
*/
gulp.task('core-lower', ['index-lower'], function(){
    console.log('Copy LOWER ENVIRONMENT core application files to the root of Angular 4 App\'s portal directory.');
    return gulp.src(['app/**', '!app/**/*.ts', '!app/**/*.scss'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('portal/app'));
});

/**
* Copy node server to portal directory.
*/
gulp.task('server', function () {
    console.log('Copy server files to the root of Angular 4 App\'s portal directory.');
    return gulp.src(['index.js', 'package.json'], { cwd: 'server/**' })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('portal'));
});

/**
* Perform all LOWER ENVIRONMENT tasks at once.
*/
gulp.task('all-lower', ['sass', 'bundle:app', 'bundle:vendorCSS', 'bundle:appCSS', 'bundle:vendorFONT', 'bundle:polyfillsJS', 'copy:vendorJS', 'compile:ts', 'core-lower', 'index-lower', 'server']);

/**
* Bundle LOWER ENVIRONMENT dependencies and app into one file (app.bundle.js).
*/
gulp.task('bundle-lower', ['all-lower'], function() {
    console.log('Copy and bundle LOWER ENVIRONMENT JavaScript dependencies into one file, app.bundle.js then drop it into Angular 4 App\'s portal directory.');
    return gulp.src([
                'portal/app/assets/js/polyfills/polyfills.js',
                'portal/app/assets/js/app/app.js'
            ])
            .pipe(concat('app.bundle.min.js'))
            .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('portal/app/assets/js'));
});

/**
* Minify HTML task. 
* (filesToCopy is intentionally an empty array in this StackOverflow Question - you don't need a list of html files do you?)
*/
gulp.task('buildmini', function() {
    console.log('Minify portal directory\'s html components.');
    var filesToCopy = [
    ];
    return gulp.src(filesToCopy, {base: './'})
            .pipe(htmlmin({ 
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                caseSensitive: true
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

/**
* Remove portal directory.
*/
gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
    console.log('Removing /portal directory.');
    return del(['portal'], cb);
});
```

**system.config.js:**

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app directory
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles, inside of node_modules
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/common/http': 'node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common-http.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries, inside of node_modules
      'jquery': 'npm:jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      'bootstrap': 'npm:bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
      '@ngx-translate/core': 'npm:@ngx-translate/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@ngx-translate/http-loader': 'npm:@ngx-translate/http-loader/bundles/http-loader.umd.js',
      'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
      'ngx-infinite-scroll': 'npm:ngx-infinite-scroll/bundles/ngx-infinite-scroll.umd.js',
      'tslib': 'npm:tslib/tslib.js',

      // charting frameworks
      'angular2-highcharts': 'npm:angular2-highcharts',
      'highcharts': 'npm:highcharts',
      'highcharts/noData':  'npm:highcharts/modules/no-data-to-display.src.js',

      'moment': 'npm:moment/moment.js',
      'ngx-bootstrap': 'npm:ngx-bootstrap',
      'bootstrap-daterangepicker': 'npm:bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js',
      'ng2-breadcrumb': 'npm:ng2-breadcrumb',
      'ng2-daterangepicker': 'npm:ng2-daterangepicker'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      highcharts: {
        main: './highcharts.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular2-highcharts': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'ngx-bootstrap': {
        format: 'cjs',
        main: 'bundles/ngx-bootstrap.umd.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'ng2-breadcrumb': {
        main: './ng2-breadcrumb.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'ng2-daterangepicker': {
        main: 'index',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
     }     
    }
  });
})(this);
```

**angular 4 package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "angular4-web-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Mark",
  "description": "Angular 4 Web App on SystemJS",
  "homepage": "https://fakehomepage.com",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" \"gulp sass\" \"gulp sass:watch\" ",
    "start:dev": "copy \"environment_dev.ts\" \"./app/shared/environment/global.constants.ts\" && npm run start",
    "start:qa": "copy \"environment_qa.ts\" \"./app/shared/environment/global.constants.ts\" && npm run start",
    "start:prod": "copy \"environment_prod.ts\" \"./app/shared/environment/global.constants.ts\" && npm run start",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "sass": "gulp sass",
    "sass:watch": "gulp sass:watch",
    "build:dev": "copy \"environment_dev.ts\" \"./app/shared/environment/global.constants.ts\" && gulp bundle-lower",
    "build:qa": "copy \"environment_qa.ts\" \"./app/shared/environment/global.constants.ts\" && gulp bundle-lower",
    "build:prod": "copy \"environment_prod.ts\" \"./app/shared/environment/global.constants.ts\" && gulp bundle-prod",
    "final": "gulp buildmini",
    "destroy": "gulp clean"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.4.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.7",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.7",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.7",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.7",
    "@angular/router": "4.4.7",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^6.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "0.0.3",
    "@types/highcharts": "^4.2.57",
    "angular2-highcharts": "^0.5.5",
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "bootstrap-social": "^5.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "~4.7.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^5.0.1",
    "highcharts": "^5.0.12",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "ng2-breadcrumb": "^0.5.14",
    "ng2-daterangepicker": "^2.0.8",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.5",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^6.0.60",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.3.0",
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-systemjs-builder": "^0.15.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^3.2.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0",
    "tslint": "^3.7.4",
    "typescript": "^2.2.2"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://bitbucket.org/mark/angular4-web-app.git"
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it can't find your file. On a side note, what are you still doing on Angular 4?  Angular 9 just came out this week. Angular 4 isn't even supported anymore. SystemJS has been removed from the Angular Ecosystem for quite a few versions now...

Comment: Legacy app - it's not an easy $ELL to business leads when recommending to do an upgrade path.

Comment: I know how that goes. I would just show them the following link and mention that this is a framework that you really can't afford to fall behind on. You really need to keep up with the releases or you could find yourself in a position (like this) where you need support for something but the only resolution is to upgrade because your version is no longer supported. https://angular.io/guide/releases#support-policy-and-schedule In this case, upgrading will give you Webpack and that will make your life *so* much easier.

Comment: Does it help at all if you use `__dirname + /somewhere/` in all of your file paths?  What stands out to me about this question is the error message using Unix forward slashes on one line and Windows backslashes on the next.  I haven't dev'd on a Windows machine in a long time, so I don't know if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Within your config files, such as webpack config or Babel, you will need to use a OS agnostic method of finding files because:

Windows uses `\` and everything else uses `/`

So require Node's built in `path` module

```
const path = require('path')
```

And in your config files use `path` and `__dirname`

```
// "target": "./dist"
"target": path(__dirname, '/dist')
```

Evidence from webpack:

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/

(Though it's not just webpack that has the issue)

Comment: This is a SystemJS configuration.

Comment: I see where you are going with this. Due to time constraints I've had to scrap this in favor of performing the exact same course of action on OSX and the usual build script worked as expected. So far, your notion of forward vs. back slash is a favorable comment.